# type of nested array with numbers

Tags: arrays, typescript

I can't seem to define the actual type of a nested array with variable elements but in a fixed format like this:

```
 [
        [ [1,[11181, ...]] ],
        [ [1,[111211, ...]] ],
        [ [1,[1111, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[11711, 1323]] ],
        [ [1,[11117, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[15111, 1243]] ],
        [ [1,[164111, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[1111, 121553]] ],
        [ [1,[1121, 12223]] ],

        ...

    ]
```

i tried :

```
private readonly _series:[[[number, number[]]]]
```

but it won't account for the variable sizes.

`private readonly _series:Array<Array[number, number[]]>`

okay, first level is Array of any number of Arrays:
`[  [x,x,x,x,x,x], [ ], [ ], [ ], ... ]`
next is where i wrote X there we have, any number of arrays of this format: `[number, number[ANY NUMBER OF ITEMS]]`

Comment: is it strictly this example, or are there other edge cases? Right now, it looks like an array, with elements that are a single-element array, that is another array, that contains two elements: a number, and then another array that can contain any length of numbers?

Comment: where "..." dots are, it means that more elements can follow, but it should be in this format in all cases. yes as you described it, it may contain any length of numbers in the last array level

Comment: I really can't tell what you're looking for.  Maybe `Array<[[number, [number, number, ...number[]]]]>` or `Array<[[number, [number, ...number[]]]]>`?  Could you possibly explicitly define what the format is?  I just can't tell what pattern I'm supposed to be picking up from this.

Comment: okay, 
first level is Array of any number of Arrays: ```[  [x,x,x,x,x,x], [ ], [ ], [ ], ... ] ```
next is where i wrote X there we have, any number of arrays of this format: 

```[number, number[ANY NUMBER OF ITEMS]]```

Comment: I guess it is `Array<Array<[number, Array<number>]>>` or `Array<[[number, Array<number>]]>` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgQSXAngHgw7HAbTAFcBbAIwFMEAadTXMq2gPgF022YBeGIgCgYIgUQCMDCePEAOSTABM4gMwAWcYo7a6w0UQlSZmmQ03qzi9do67RYhdNMxzllW48urNu-sMCZAHZnVW8dPREDR2NxQLcfCIcjAFZjSzUVBPsoowA2DRCw20ScgLSvcWTkzPDs-2llS0Ui3Q4gA

Comment: @TMvytKA9LgSVZ8Z7 please edit your question instead of providing details in the comments

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, I was not sure about how many times I can  nest this <>

Comment: I don't think I'm getting it.  If it's *not* `Array<[[number, number[]]>`, please write explicitly where that goes wrong.

Comment: this is the correct answer for my case ```Array<Array<[number, Array<number>]>>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[number, number[]]][]` is your answer but that's an unreadable mess.

Let's work through it from the inside out, and alias some names.

An array of numbers of any length:

`[11711, 1323]` = `number[]`

That becomes the second element in array where the first element is a number:

`[1,[11711, 1323]]` = `[number, number[]]` -- call this `NumTuple` for clarity

These `NumTuple`s are always the single element in an array:

`[ [1, [11711, 1323] ] ]`  = `[NumTuple]`

And you have a whole array of them:

`[NumTuple][]`

```
type NumTuple = [number, number[]];

const numbers: [NumTuple][] = [
        [ [1,[11181, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[111211,  123, 123, 123, 123, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[1111, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[11711, 1323]] ],
        [ [1,[11117, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[15111, 1243]] ],
        [ [1,[164111, 123]] ],
        [ [1,[1111, 121553]] ],
        [ [1,[1121, 12223]] ],
    ]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwCpzAG2gXigbQHaIBGEATgDRQELEk4C6dA3ALABQbAxgPZ4DOwlIqV4AuXPGSoMdelGw42UJcqU5cARjI51OgByao6gEwBmCsbOHT561ZMModMopXK12rTuM6Kdm5Yt-fwcnF1dcDU8vIL9YwLsQ51Zw1UjtdQB2H0MTU0Sw13dNdJ0M4LpHJJSIj20AVmirABZ7CtDklKLPADYmxot8jvCukoNvOrrWyoKVEZ0jMaMlqfaVOiA)